# How to delete part of the row in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to remove rows by specific Criteria.
My approach is to autofilter first and then delete the rows that satisfy Criterias

This code removed the entire rows. I only need the part which belongs to the "currentregion" to be removed.

```vb
Range("A3").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="True"
Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Offset(1).Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

This code copies what I want. But when the syntax changed to "delete", it deleted the entire row.

```
Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Offset(1).copy Sheets("WorkSheet2").Range("A1")
```

I checked the definition. The CurrentRegion in VBA refers to a range bounded by any combination of blank rows and blank columns.

Answer (score 1):

- `Copy` method only copies the visible cells. But `Delete` method doesn't work in the same way.
- Use `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` to get the visible range.

Please try.

```vb
Sub demo()
    Dim visRng As Range
    Range("A3").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="True"
    With Range("A3").CurrentRegion
        Set visRng = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    End With
    Range("A3").AutoFilter
    If Not visRng Is Nothing Then visRng.Columns("A:D").Delete xlUp
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.Resize property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144187)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Range.SpecialCells method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144203)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick help, I tried but the code still remove entire row (I do have content that should not be removed in the same row) I also tried Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Columns("A:D").Offset(1).Delete Shift:=xlUp bu the code delect whole rows too.

Comment: The question is what do you want to remove. Is it the visible cells' contents on Col4?

Comment: I have a table range from column A to column D. I only need to remove the row within the table range. All content beside the table range should not be removed.

Comment: Does `Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Select` select your table (Column A to D) or more than 4 columns?

Comment: I tried the select and then use select.delete, the result is still the entire row been removed. This issue cost me almost a day and I'm still not able to resolve it.

Comment: Does Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Select select your table (Column A to D) or more than 4 columns?  Please run this code line only and answer the question. I must know if your table is sepertated with other data on sheet or not before I revise the code.

Comment: I've updated the code to remove only col A:D. If it isn't your expected output, please edit your post share the data layout on sheet.

Answer (score 0):

If [taller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22192445/taller) doesn't mind, I made a small modification of his code.

```
Option Explicit

Sub demo_HunterZ()
    Dim visRng      As Range
    
    ' Sheet1 ' Change the sheet codename according to your sheet codename
    If Sheet1.FilterMode Then Sheet1.ShowAllData
    If Sheet1.AutoFilterMode Then Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = False
    If Sheet1.Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count = 1 Then Exit Sub
    Sheet1.Range("A3").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="True"

    On Error Resume Next
    Set visRng = Sheet1.Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Resize(Sheet1.Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = False
    If Not visRng Is Nothing Then visRng.Delete xlUp
End Sub
```